# Should an interpolation coincide the original function on the given data points?

Tags: interpolation

Suppose having a model $f(x)=y$ where $f$ is unkown. Moreover, suppose you  have some data points for this model i.e. $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), \dots , (x_n,y_n)$. 
If one can find an approximate of $f $ called $\tilde{f}$ using the given data points.

When such aproximation is called interpolation? should the approximation vanish on the given data points in order to be considered as an interpolation ( i.e. $\tilde{f}(x_i)=y_i$ for all $i$) ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "approximate a model by an explicit expression,using given data points" and "vanishing" approximation? What do you mean by approximating a model?

Comment: I edited my question, please check it @Tim

Comment: Interpolation takes certain data points as given and could not do anything otherwise. Any estimation method that doesn't reproduce those points, or leave them as given, is not an interpolation method, as least as I have ever met the term.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65532/interpolation-extrapolation-and-approximations-rigorously

Comment: @Nick Your sense of "interpolation" may be unduly restrictive, because it would exclude very popular techniques such as various forms of splines, kriging with a nugget, loess (and other smoothers), and even linear regression. Many people distinguish interpolators that "honor the data" from those that do not, but they do not declare the latter techniques to be non-interpolators.

Comment: @whuber Point taken, but conversely, your sense of interpolation seems  generous. I wouldn't regard loess and related methods as interpolators. although their use for estimating local summaries is often akin to interpolation.

Comment: @Nick I think this may be a case of multiple communities addressing similar problems with different assumptions and interests. To a mathematician, an "interpolator" must agree with the givens (the "data"). But when we deal with real data in a statistical application, it almost always is the case that we are uncertain about their values. In that respect it 's usually a bad idea for an interpolator to honor the data: that's a severe form of over-fitting. From this statistical point of view Loess, an OLS fit, and any prediction procedure whatsoever is a genuine interpolator.

Comment: @whuber Indeed; territorial distinctions can bite here. I have often been struck by how few statistics texts now even consider interpolation (strict sense) at all, even though it can be useful in data management. Older books on the "combination of observations" certainly included interpolation. But I guess it's now hard to distinguish between interpolation (wide sense) and smoothing; perhaps we just decide that's not a problem to keep us awake at night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolation usually means $\tilde{f}(x_i)=y_i$ for all $i$.

There are other methods where we don't require $\tilde{f}(x_i)=y_i$ for all $i$, but these methods are not usually referred to as interpolation.

Comment: Thank you for your aswer, but would you please add on what evidence did you base you answer ?  a definition , reference ...;

Comment: I just knew this, but here's one source: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Interpolation.html

Comment: As I clarify in a comment to the question, this is a *mathematical* answer to a statistical question.  As such I think it's misleading in this context.

Comment: @whuber I have said in my answer that there are other methods, but that these methods are not referred to as interpolation.

Comment: Alas, they *are* referred to as interpolation.  See the literature on time series, spatial analysis, or stochastic processes, *inter alia*.  Some people, but definitely not all, call this ["inexact interpolation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=inexact+interpolation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). One well recognized authority, Noel Cressie, actually equates the words "smoothing" and "interpolation." He sees "smoothing (or interpolation) , filtering, and prediction" as all being the same thing, which he calls "spatial prediction" (*Statistics for Spatial Data*, 1st Ed., pp 105-6).